# Cmake cross dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake

I stuck with a CMake problem.

I have a project structure:

Module A (source + include)
Module B (source + include)

Module A creates library (add_library),
Module B uses library from A (add_executable),

The Module A uses a one file from the Module B.
How should I solve it? The Module B should create library with one file to compile the library A and executable file?

Best Regards!

Comment: The standard solution is to pull out that common file into a third module that both A and B would depend on, or move it into A (if that makes sense for your project).

Comment: "*The Module A uses a one file from the Module B*"... sounds like you should redesign your project (as suggested in the above comment) so that this is avoided, because it suggests a circular dependency.

Comment: How do you know the "file belongs to target X", if you use it in both? What kind of logic is implemented in this file that requires it to be present in both modules?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will move the file to the separate module. This is good solution. Thanks!